# Complete Lie algebras and its nilradical

Tags: lie-algebras

For complete Lie algebras I found that the research in this branch is based on the nilradical, even more in french thesis called "Algèbres de Lie complètes"  of Michel Favre, available here: https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/30637 , I found this phrase "L'étude des algèbres de Lie complètes est donc entièrement ramenée à celle du plus grand idéal nilpotent et de ses dérivations."
which is translated by "The study of algebras complete Lie algebras is therefore entirely reduced to that of the nilradical and its derivations."

But I don't know why this is true since the thesis don't discuss this point. Can somone help?

N.B:
A Lie algebra $L$ is called a complete Lie algebra, if $L$ satisfies the two conditions
$Z(L) = 0$, and $\operatorname{Der} L = \operatorname{ad} L$.

Comment: I think this sentence is quite informal and vague. Where did you find the thesis?

Comment: Indeed any semisimple Lie algebra is complete and they all have trivial nilradical so as stated it isn't quite true.

Comment: @Callum Having a look at the given thesis, the quotation is p.II (p.4 of the pdf). I seems implicit in this conclusion that the author assumes that the Lie algebra has no nonzero semisimple ideal.

Comment: Your sentence *"the thesis don't discuss this point"* is not quite true: the whole paragraph (p.I-II, p.3-4 in the pdf) finishing with this sentence somewhat justifies this sentence.